# Launch Chrome with a specific Homepage using Selenium-Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I am trying to launch Chrome with a specific Homepage set. Given below is the code, I am using:

```
package WebDriverInitialization;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class LaunchChrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Technology Lab\\+ProgramFiles\\selenium-drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

        Map<String, Object> hmPrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hmPrefs.put( "browser.startup.page", 1);
        hmPrefs.put( "browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.seleniumhq.org");

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", hmPrefs);

        DesiredCapabilities chromeCaps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        chromeCaps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

        WebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeCaps);
        chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get a blank page with 'data:,' in the URL - like how Chrome launches by default. Last line of the code is getting executed and the page is maximized.

I am using Selenium version `3.0.1`; java version `1.8.0_92`; Chrome version `56.0.2924.87` and ChromeDriver version `2.27.440174` on `Windows 7 Professional SP1 x64`.

Can anyone point out the mistake in above code and get it to launch Chrome with `http://www.seleniumhq.org` as the homepage?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any calls to navigate to a particular page. Have you tried chromedriver.navigate.to(<url>)?

Comment: My objective is to launch chrome with a specific homepage without needing to navigate to a url.

Comment: have you tried with `chromeCaps .setCapability("chrome.switches",
        Arrays.asList("--homepage=http://www.seleniumhq.org"));`

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬 Thanks. This also doesn't seem to work. Launches chrome with 'data:,' in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`chromeOptions.setArguments("google-base-url=MY_URL");`

From doc: [Define kGoogleBaseURL](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/google/core/browser/google_switches.cc?q=kGoogleBaseURL&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=10)

> Specifies an alternate URL to use for speaking to Google. Useful for testing.